# How to add standard symbolic constants with bitwise operators (like ORs)

Tags: ida, debugging-symbols

I am working with IDA and I have the `OpenProcess` function receiving `dwDesireAccess` of `0x410`:

[image]

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx) we can see that `0x410` is the result of `OR` between two access rights:

```
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION (0x0400)
PROCESS_VM_READ (0x0010)
```

How can I set a standard symbolic constant such as
`PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ` ?

I must do it manually (with "Manual...")?

This is only what I have:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a [bitfield enum](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/500.shtml). Since the enum containing `PROCESS_VM_READ` already exists in the MSSDK type library, we are going to copy that and modify it to become a bitfield.

1. Go to the enums subview, then right click and **Add enum...** (press <kbd>Insert</kbd> on Windows).
   [image]
2. Click **Add standard enum by symbol name**.
   [image]
3. Find `PROCESS_VM_READ`, then click **OK**.
   [image]
4. A new enum called `MACRO_PROCESS` should be added. Expand it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> or right click → **Unhide**)
5. Delete the enum member `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` (press <kbd>U</kbd> when selecting it).
   [image]
6. Right click and choose **Edit enum...** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>).
7. Check **Bitfield**, then click **OK**. (This step will fail if you don't perform step 5)
   [image]

Now the MACRO_PROCESS bitfield should appear when you hit <kbd>M</kbd> on 410h, and should appear as something like

```
mov     eax, PROCESS_VM_READ or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION
```

Comment: great answer ! Why you delete `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` ?

Comment: @E235: See step 7's description.

Comment: Any idea why it will fail ? 
I want to understand because maybe I will have a case when I will need also this last parameter.

Comment: I think the problem is the intersecting masks (which I think default to the values themselves). If in the code you ever have the value 1F0FFFh, it will be replaced by a bitwise OR of all other constants. You could also define it as a standalone constant (e.g. an enum containing only that, might be a better way). Unless there are some hidden options here, this bitfields feature feels a bit unfinished (unless you don't have any duplicates or intersections).